# How to write script to download csv file of ideas for product category in google adwords

Tags: download, automation, keyword, bots, google-ads-api

I want download search volume trends from google adwords based on the target location and product category. Can Someone guide me to write a script that can automate the process.

If download is not possible, let it share to my google drive account with the specified name(category name)

Edit:

I am trying to automate the below process for an Adwords - Keyword planner.

1. Login to adwords
2. Select Target location
3. Input Category and click on Get Ideas
4. Downloading the keyword ideas as CSV and save it.

Something like a PHP bot

Answer (score -1):

Since you're considering

> to write a script that can automate the process

One way this can be done, is via [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)'s **[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx)**. And it's `.DownloadFile Method (String address, String fileName)`. The scripts (Cmdlets) actually are specialized .NET classes, which the PowerShell runtime instantiates and invokes when they are run. Cmdlets derive either from Cmdlet or from PSCmdlet, the latter being used when the cmdlet needs to interact with the PowerShell runtime. Also The implementation of these cmdlet classes can refer to any .NET API and may be in any .NET language.